# Switch/Case Java return to main menu

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, return, case

I'm writing a program for my Java class and I need to make a receipt like output. I have to allow the user to choose from 3 items. After choosing the item, they choose the quantity, and i multiply that by the price to give them a total. The user needs to pick all 3 items, but can pick them in any order. I am trying to make a Switch/Case method to help me assign the variables to what the user has chosen. This is what I have currently done:

```
System.out.println("Enter name of First item");
System.out.println(" 1. Gum, 2. Soda, 3. Chips");
firstItem = keyboard.nextInt();
switch (firstItem) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Gum");
        System.out.println(gumPrice);
        System.out.println("How many packs of gum would you like to purchase?");
        gumBought = keyboard.nextInt();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Soda");
        System.out.println(sodaPrice);
        System.out.println("How many cups of soda would you like to purchase?");
        sodaBought = keyboard.nextInt();
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Chips");
        System.out.println(chipsPrice);
        System.out.println("How many bags of chips would you like to purchase?");
        chipsBought = keyboard.nextInt();
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Unknown Entry");
        break;
}
```

And Then it begins the second item Switch/Case. I Need to know how to get it to return to the Main Question (Gum/Soda/Chips) if the user picks a number outside of 1-3 or picks the same number/item twice. How can I do this efficiently?

Also, can I use Strings instead of Int to allow the user to type "Gum" instead of "1"? Thanks.

Comment: In java 7+ you can use Strings as your switch cases

Comment: Have you tried using a `loop`, or using a `String` as the input type for your `switch-case`?

Comment: is it variable = keyboard.nextLine();

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation on `switch-case with Strings` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

I am hesitant to give a complete working example, so I will provide you with snippets to get you on the right track for using `Strings`.

First off, if you want to repeat an algorithm until a condition is met, you can use a `loop` to provide you with what you are searching for.

```
while (condition) {
    //do something
}
```

Since Java 7 was released, the `switch-case` can be used with Strings. You just need to change your input type to match what you're desiring:

```
System.out.print("Enter name of your item [gum] [soda] [chips]: ");
String choice = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
```

Then you will have to modify your `switch-case` syntax.

```
switch (choice) {//now String
    case "gum":
    case "soda":
    case "chips":
    default:
}
```

Hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: i'm receiving these 2 errors: Lab1.java:31: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
  switch (choice)
          ^
Lab1.java:63: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String
required: int
    switch (choice2)
            ^
2 errors

Comment: im using jEdit 5.2 and have Java 8 downloaded so i should be able to use Strings in a switch statement

Comment: Make sure `choice` is a String and that the cases are of type String - i.e. wrapped in double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

- Give the user a choice to exit with '9'
- Put the switch statement in a `while()` loop

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double gumPrice, sodaPrice, chipsPrice;

    gumPrice = 1.25;
    sodaPrice = 4.00;
    chipsPrice = 3.25;

    while(true){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name of First item");
    System.out.println(" 1. Gum, 2. Soda, 3. Chips, 9. EXIT");
    int firstItem = keyboard.nextInt( );

    switch (firstItem){
        case 1:
           System.out.println("Gum");
           System.out.println(gumPrice);
           System.out.println("How many packs of gum would you like to purchase?");
           int gumBought = keyboard.nextInt();
           break;
        case 2:
           System.out.println("Soda");
           System.out.println(sodaPrice);
           System.out.println("How many cups of soda would you like to purchase?");
           int sodaBought = keyboard.nextInt();
            break;
        case 3:
           System.out.println("Chips");
           System.out.println(chipsPrice);
           System.out.println("How many bags of chips would you like to purchase?");
           int chipsBought = keyboard.nextInt();
           break;
        case 9:
           return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete the `loop` variable and just use `while(true)`